# form submission using ruby rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am trying to develop a rack based web application

**config.ru** is

```
use Rack::Static,
:urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
:root => "Rack"
run lambda { |env|
[
 200,
{
  'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
},
File.open('home.html', File::RDONLY)
]
}
```

**home.html** is

```
<form action="Rack.rb" method="get">
  name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and ruby file    **Rack.rb** is

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class HelloWorld
 def response
  [200, {}, ['Hello World']]
 end
end

class HelloWorldApp
 def self.call(env)
   HelloWorld.new.response
 end
end

Rack::Server.start :app => HelloWorldApp
```

Output is

```
 INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
 INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20475        port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:48 +0530] "GET /Rack.rb?    name=rfg&age=dfg&email=dfg&hobbies=d HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0006
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:48 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1"  200 - 0.0004
 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:54 +0530] "GET /Rack.rb?     name=rt&age=21 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0005
```

I need to parse the input from the GET request .How to do it?

Comment: I believe you should change the `action="Rack.rb"`, it's can be url.

Comment: currently you see the form and available click submit?

Comment: yes . how to get the submitted details in rack ruby file?

Comment: after submitting form what's going on?

Comment: please clarify _nothing happening_. Any errors in log file? Anything else?

Comment: [2015-07-31 16:57:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-31 16:57:42] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-07-31 16:57:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20475 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:48 +0530] "GET /Rack.rb?name=rfg&age=dfg&email=dfg&hobbies=d HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0006
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:48 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0004
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2015:16:57:54 +0530] "GET /Rack.rb?name=rt&age=rt&email=rt&hobbies=rtyrtyrtyrty HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0005

Comment: Please format and post it, into question, not in comment.

Comment: i want to print the submitted details in console . How?